# Restart my nodejs app (with pm2) from php server

Tags: php, node.js, nginx, github, pm2

I just got a problem, I'm using the webhook for github ( I wrote one in php ).

The problem, I want to restart my nodejs app with pm2 from my php code something like that :

```
shell_exec("pm2 restart test");
```

but my user : www-data (nginx) can't execute it.. When I try it log in as www-data I got this :

> Error: EACCES, permission denied '/.pm2'
>       at Error (native)
>       at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:747:18)
>       at Object.CLI.pm2Init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/CLI.js:40:8)
>       at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2:21:5)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
>       at startup (node.js:129:16)

And I don't want to use "sudo" because it's not really clean, do you have an idea ? Thank you very much by advance :)

Comment: There are still situations where you want to be able to manipulate the pm2 library from a PHP API.  I am dealing with the same situation right now and --watch is not an option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I got a solution, it's fixed.

I just had to run my app with this line :

```
pm2 start app.js --watch
```

Then it's watch when a file is modified and restart it automaticly.

Comment: Your question and the answer didn't match

Answer (score 0):

Set the right HOME environment variable when running the command

```
$ HOME=/home/USER pm2 restart test
```